# Magento 2.3.1 installation Error

Tags: installation, magento2.3.1

I am installing Magento 2.3.1 but installation stops at 76% what an issue

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYDF2.jpg

[image]

Comment: What error was thrown in the installation console?

Comment: @RajMohanR please check screenshot link above

Comment: @RajMohanR i have uploaded the screenshot please check the console error

Comment: In the link above it seems like your site is installed anyway. Just run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` to be sure everything is installed.

Comment: Your installation seems to be complete you can proceed with rest as said by @ArnoVandeCappelle

Comment: @RajMohanR please see this screenshot 
https://imgur.com/a/sMvKOJa 
everything is broken on site

Comment: Have you executed the two commands bin/magento setup:upgrade and bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f . Can you also please share the screenshot of console errors of home page?

Answer (score 1):

You can try install your magento by command line:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --backend-frontname="admin" \
--key="6f798255dfa145f15cbc9721901a8689" \
--db-host="localhost" \
--db-name="database_name" \
--db-user="user_database" \
--db-password="password_database" \
--language="en_US" \
--currency="USD" \
--timezone="America/Chicago" \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--use-secure=0 \
--base-url="http://domain.com/" \
--base-url-secure="https://domain.com/" \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password="admin123" \
--admin-email=admin@gmail.com \
--admin-firstname=Admin \
--admin-lastname=Magento
```

change your information and run it.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems issue is in your server only.You can check the installation console for more details.
I suggest, Try again and keep your eye on installation console and server and MySQL also.

Answer (score 0):

you have some internal redirect from `https` to `http`, this breaks installation.

> do not use `https://` if you dont have ssl certificate

later when you get `https` certificate, change your base store url to `https://`, and use https rewrite.